# I am writing a programm in which user enter a amount and programm display tax due calculatig percntage of tax as per thier income group?

Tags: c

Problem that I am facing with program is that, when I enter an amount below 750, it calculates and displays the correct taxable amount, and same when I enter an amount between range of 750 to 2250, but when I enter an amount above 2250 then I'm getting a wrong answer

For example, when I entered 3000 the answer should be 60, but it is calculating 52.50 which means that instead of getting multiplied with 3, it is getting multiplied with 2 and surprisingly it is adding 37.50 but not multiplying with 3/100.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ){

    float inm;

    printf( "Enter the amount of taxable  income:" );
    scanf( "%f", &inm );

    if ( inm < 750 ){
        printf( "tax due :%f", inm * 1 / 100 );
    }
    else if ( inm >= 750 || inm <= 2250 ){
        printf( "tax due :%f", inm = 7.50 + ( ( inm - 750 ) * 2 / 100 ) );
    }
    else if ( inm >= 2251 || inm <= 3750 ){

        //problem in the following line (inm - 2250) not getting multiplied by 3/100
        printf( "tax due :%f", inm = 37.50 + ( ( inm - 2250 ) * 3 / 100 ) );

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: better use switch case...

Answer (score 1):

You need `&&` instead of `||` in if conditions.

In your code for `inm = 3000` second if-case-condition pass because you use `||` condition that evaluates   52.... ([check what is happening, and what you need both](http://codepad.org/mkbVBEuE))

In your, code the third case is in else part of second `if`. You have nested `if`s, whereas you need sequential ifs, remove else.

```
if(inm<750){
    printf("tax due :%f",inm*1/100);
}
if(inm>=750 && inm<=2250){
    printf("tax due :%f",inm=7.50+((inm-750)*2/100));
}
if(inm>=2251 && inm<=3750){
    printf("tax due :%f",inm=37.50+((inm-2250)*3/100));
}
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/ASyItrGE)

Addtionally, [indent](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html) your code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Grijesh Chauhan is correct.

And you may want to write code as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ){

    float inm;

    printf( "Enter the amount of taxable  income:" );
    scanf( "%f", &inm );

    if ( inm < 750 ){
        printf( "tax due :%f", inm * 1 / 100 );
    }
    else if (inm <= 2250 ){
        printf( "tax due :%f", inm = 7.50 + ( ( inm - 750 ) * 2 / 100 ) );
    }
    else if (inm <= 3750 ){
        printf( "tax due :%f", inm = 37.50 + ( ( inm - 2250 ) * 3 / 100 ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Enter the amount of taxable  income:3000
tax due :60.000000
```